# Forming adverbs from 하다 verbs: 히 vs. 하게

Tags: adverbs

In some cases there are two ways to make an adverb from a 하다 verb.  Is there any difference in meaning or nuance between them?

As an example, what's the difference between 침착히 and 침착하게 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, no difference.

There are two ways to convert a verb or adjective to adverb, one is by adding 게 (i.e. 침착하게), another one is adding a 이,히,... component (i.e. 침착히).

깨끗하다 => 깨끗이, 빠르다 => 빨리, 다르다 => 달리, 지극하다 => 지극히

Which one to use depends on practice of natives. For example 빨리 is much more commonly used then 빠르게.

Comment: Since Super Cool answered the essential question of difference first, I best credit him with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Normally there's no difference, but there's at least one case where it makes a difference.  Some verbs take another verb/adjective with -게 form as complement:

> 자동차를 **더 안전하게** 만들었다. = [They] made the cars (to be) **safer**.
>
> 나는 하늘을 **새빨갛게** 그렸다. = I painted the sky **bright red**.
>
> 선물 세트를 실물보다 **크게** 광고했다. = [They] advertised the gift set as **bigger** than it actually was.

However, they can also act like adverbs, simply modifying the verb, so sometimes it can become ambiguous:

> 보고서를 **침착하게** 만들었다. = I made the report calmly.  (Not ambiguous, because a report can't be "calm".)
>
> 나는 자동차를 **빠르게** 그렸다. = "I drew/depicted the car as fast." or "I drew the car quickly."

On the other hand, -이/히/리/기 forms are syntactically adverbs and can only act as such:

> 책상을 **빨리** 만들었다. = [They] made a desk **quickly**.
>
> 그림을 **조용히** 그렸다. = [I] painted **in silence**.

Comment: The ~게 만들다 form, by the way, is not a complement, it is a "long causative" in Korean grammar.  I'm 98% sure all the other uses you describe are adverbial, aren't they?  Anyone else have an opinion about that?  Thanks for your input here

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of most commonly used Korean adverbs.
[korean adverbs list](https://koreanly.com/korean-adverbs//)

가끔 / 때로는 - sometimes

가볍게 - lightly
자연스럽게 - naturally
가장 - most
계속 - continuously
곧 - soon
그때는 - at that time, back then
나쁘게 - badly
누가 - who
단순히 - simply
더 - more
덜 - less
드물게 - rarely
때때로 / 종종 - occasionally
맛있게 - deliciously
몇이나 - how many
무려 - as many as
무례하게 - rudely
뭐 - what
바쁘게 - busily
밝게 - brightly
보통 / 대개 - usually
불과 - only
아름답게 - beautifully
아주/매우 - very
아직 - yet
안전하게 - safely
어느 - which
어디 - where
어떻게 - how
어렵게 - difficultly
언제 - when
언젠가 - some time
얼마나 - how much
엄청 - enormously
완전히 - perfectly
왜 - why
용기있게 - bravely
위험하게 - dangerously
이쁘게 - prettily
이제 - now
자주 / 흔히 - frequently
잘 - well
재미있게 - funny
절대 - never
절대로 - absolutely
조용하게 - quietly
지금 - now (time)
편하게 - comfortably
항상 - always
행복하게 - happily

1000 Korean adverbs

https://koreanly.com/korean-adverbs/